# Unmanaged extensions taking JSON as parameter

Tags: java, json, neo4j

I'm trying to build an extension to dynamically insert some data in neo4j to no avail.

This is my extension code :

```
@Path("/inserter")
public class Inserter {

    private final GraphDatabaseService db;

    public Inserter(@Context GraphDatabaseService db){
        this.db = db;
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/insert")
    public void insert(Person x){   
        
        Transaction tr = db.beginTx();
        
        //Do something
        
        tr.success();
        tr.finish();
    }
}
```

And this is my Person object :

```
package org.neo4j.server.plugin.plugin.messages;

public class Person {
    public String name;
    public int id;
    public String email;
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

I tried a lot of different methods but none worked so far. With the code above a get a 415 error saying **"Unsupported Media Type"**

I tried to add the jackson json provider to my project. It changed my error but I cannot figure out how to handle this. The error is now :

> Error 500 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.getFactory()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory;
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.getFactory()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory;

To test my extension I'm using the Google REST console, setting the RequestUri as localhost:7474/myextensions/inserter/insert, the Content-Type as application/json and the Request body is the following :

> {"id":100,"name":"Bibi","email":"yopmail"}

EDIT : Here is the maven dependency tree (not sure it was exactly the same that caused me trouble because I changed lot of code since my question)

```
[INFO] org.neo4j.server.plugin:neo4j-antvoice-plugin:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.neo4j:neo4j:jar:2.0.0-M03:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:2.0.0-M03:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-index:jar:2.0.0-M03:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:3.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-algo:jar:2.0.0-M03:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-udc:jar:2.0.0-M03:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-matching:jar:2.0.0-M03:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher:jar:2.0.0-M03:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-jmx:jar:2.0.0-M03:compile
[INFO] +- org.neo4j:server-api:jar:2.0.0-M03:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j.3rdparty.javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.2.r612:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO]    \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.2.1:compile
```

Comment: Your `NoSuchMethodError` is probably there because you mix Jackson versions.

Comment: That's a possibility but I only use one version for my project. Maybe Neo4j is using another version that I don't see

Comment: can you post the output of `mvn dependency:tree` to find the cause? It very much looks like a version error with your project libs. What version of neo4j and jackson are you using?

Comment: @PeterNeubauer, the result is in my Edit

Answer (score 0):

The error "Unsupported Media Type" is due to there is some mismatch in your methos and in your ajax call. Here I can see your method is post, so you have to call this method by post format.

See if it works.

json_array*= [{"id":100,"name":"Bibi","email":"yopmail"}]

```
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url :'http://localhost:8080/inserter/insert',
cache: false,
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: 'json',
data:json_array,
success:function(data){},
error:function(response,status) {}
});
```

Comment: I'm doing a POST with the REST console it still does not work