# Jersey, JSON API, "415 Unsupported Media Type"

Tags: java, json, jersey

I'm getting started with Java so expect this to be a pretty amateur problem. I'm modifying Neo4j's unmanaged extension template.

I've defined an `NTReport` class, it is included, everything compiles happily. POSTing against the endpoint with content-type set to `application/json` returns the error in the subject.

I also have the `getStatus` method defined in the object.

```
package org.neo4j.example.unmanagedextension;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine;
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionResult;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.*;
import org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil;
import org.neo4j.server.database.CypherExecutor;
import org.neo4j.example.unmanagedextension.NTReport;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Path("/service")
public class MyService {

    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Path("/reports")
    public String getReportJava(NTReport report) {
        return "Report params: " + report.getMetrics();
    }
}
```

Here's `NTReport`:

```
package org.neo4j.example.unmanagedextension;
public class NTReport {
    private String endpoints;
    private String resolution;
    private String metrics;

    public String getEndpoints() {
        return this.endpoints;
    }

    public String getResolution() {
        return this.resolution;
    }

    public String getMetrics() {
        return this.metrics;
    }
}
```

My understanding is that by using `@Consumes`, it should map keys in JSON to variables of the same name in the class. Am I wrong there?

When I create basic endpoints using `@GET`, I get the expected responses.

**ALSO**, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692869/unmanaged-extensions-taking-json-as-parameter) post appears to describe the same exact problem, so I'll examine it.

I found another error log that seems to suggest it doesn't know how to handle JSON after all.

```
Feb 11, 2015 5:46:19 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest getEntity
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class org.neo4j.example.unmanagedextension.NTReport, and Java type class org.neo4j.example.unmanagedextension.NTReport, and MIME media type application/json was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
```

Comment: Could you please add `NTReport`?

Comment: What is your JSON-to-Java binding provider?

Comment: Also, added more code to my post.

Comment: I see that you are using Jersey 2. Please take a look at [this](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json). You need to add [json provider](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers/) (if not already).

Comment: Removing my earlier comment, it looks like I may not have the right provider loaded... I'll update my question with more info.

Comment: I was wrong. neo4j community server uses jersey 1.9. You may try to add `jersey-json` module and [@XmlRootElement](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.9/json.html#d4e921) or choose any other option

Answer (score 0):

[jersey-json](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-json/1.9) [provides](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/1.9/json.html) a set of `MessageBodyReader<T>` and `MessageBodyWriter<T>`. You may add [@XmlRootElement](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/1.9/json.html#d4e921) to your `NTReport` or choose any other option available for jersey 1.x since neo4j community server [uses Jersey 1.9](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-java-rest-client-example.html) at the moment

Comment: Could you give me some examples of implementing that? I added the dependency to `pom.xml` but the class doesn't seem to recognize `@XmlRootElement`.

Comment: JAXB requires default constructor. I.e `NTReport() {}`. Make sure to add it as well

Comment: Yep, just noticed that. `import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
` makes `@XmlRootElement` work, too. I'm going through that second link in your answer now, filling in gaps...

Comment: Also, there are no setter methods. I'm not sure whether or not JAXB would be able to set private fields. You may add another constructor.

Comment: Saw that, too. I'm still getting the last error in my initial question, though. I added it not long ago, in case you didn't see. It feels as though a provider entity needs to be added somehow for JSON?

Comment: Strange. `jersey-json` should register relevant message body reader

Comment: Did you rebuild with maven?

Comment: Yes, I clean and rebuild every time.

Comment: If I adjust it with [this](https://gist.github.com/subvertallchris/8e06ac23584711fc822a), it returns whatever I give it, now.

Comment: That's because it requires `StringProvider`.  There should be `JSONRootElementProvider` among providers. Are you sure that list of providers is the same as before? Also,  did jersey-json appear in mvn dependency tree?